# Django merge QuerySet while keeping the order

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

i'm trying to join together 2 QuerySets. Right now, I'm using the `|` operator, but doing it this way won't function as an "append".

My current code is:

```
df = RegForm((querysetA.all() | querysetB.all()).distinct())
```

I need the elements from querysetA to be before querysetB. Is it even possible to accomplish while keeping them just queries?

Comment: it creates a union query in the database, so not it's not possible (at least not in general).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be solved by using [**`annotate`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) to add a custom field for ordering on the querysets, and use that in a [**`union`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#union) like this:

```
from django.db.models import Value

a = querysetA.annotate(custom_order=Value(1))
b = querysetB.annotate(custom_order=Value(2))
a.union(b).order_by('custom_order')
```

Prior to [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2), you need to specify the `output_field` for `Value`:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField

a = querysetA.annotate(custom_order=Value(1, IntegerField()))
b = querysetB.annotate(custom_order=Value(2, IntegerField()))
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what i needed.